# how to show menu styles in react-select outside scroll in table?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

[image]

I want to show the menus outside the table, I tried using position:"absolute" in menu:styles, but didn't work.

```
<Select styles={customStyles}
        onChange={handleChange}
        options={options}
        autoFocus={true}
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to read the [documentation on Portaling](https://react-select.com/advanced#portaling). Currently your menu is confined to it's container element, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing.